# Hyperlink in Oracle Reports (.RDF) Content using Oracle Report Builder

Tags: oracle, reporting-services, hyperlink, oraclereports

I am not sure if this is the correct forum to ask this question,

I am currently creating an oracle report (.RDF) using Oracle Report Builder and my client wants me to place hyperlinks in the content instead of putting URL in the content.

This report is going to be generated as PDF.

**My current sentence looks like**

> Click here (http://international.usp.ac.fj/?page_id=114) to see USP
>   member countries.

The URL automatically converts to hyperlink in the above sentence.

**What my client wants:**

> Click [here](http://international.usp.ac.fj/?page_id=114) to see USP member countries.

I tried to look for an option where I can use HTML `<a>` tag.

I would like to know if there is a way to include hyperlinks in Oracle Reports.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you could in order to achieve this is, select property inspector of item you would like to have hyperlink and choose  `Hyperlink`.

[image]

Also choose Yes for `Contains HTML Tags`.

Format for passing dynamic values in URL is

`http://www.google.com?pid=&DEPTNO` where DEPTNO is the value in report.

**Update**

This is what I did to achieve your expected output, you could modify based on your requirements

- Created sql query for the source

  > select 'Click here' txt from dual

[image]

- Select Property Inspector for the field

[image]

- Added link in `Hyperlink` property and selected `Yes` in `Contains
  HTML Tags`

[image]

- To see the output, generate report as PDF or run report in web
  browser.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your response, I tried to put a hyperlink on the `boilerplate text object` but it didn't work. The `Contains HTML Tags` property worked fine for other tags except `<a>`. [About HTML formatting](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/bi.1111/b32122/orbr_concepts2008.htm#CHDECIEA)